# insertar subdocumentos a un documento con mongoose desde nodeJS a mongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

estoy probando con mongoose desde nodeJS un método para agregar subdocumentos a un documento en mongoDB, por el momento no me esta siendo posible poder agregar, por el momento tengo esto

```
    const updateAbono = (req, res = response) => {
  const deudorId = req.params._id;
  const abonado = req.body; 

  Deudor.updateOne( { deudorId } ,
     {$push: {abonos: abonado} },
    (error, sucess) => {
      if (error ) {
        console.log(error);
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ message: "Error al actualizar el abono" });
      } 
      else{
          console.log(sucess)
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Se agrego el abono con exito" });
      }
    });
  };
```

este es mi modelo

```
const DeudorSchema = Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    prestado: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    interes:{
        type: Number, 
        required: false
    },
    saldo: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    },
    fecha: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    abonos: [
        {
            abono:{
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            fechaAbono: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

No se me ejecuta ningún error, pero al imprimir el sucess se me imprime esto, seria de gran ayuda la que me puedan dar.

```
    {
  n: 0,
  nModified: 0,
  opTime: {
    ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 8, high_: 1613768160 },
    t: 7
  },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000007,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 8, high_: 1613768160 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 8, high_: 1613768160 }
}
```

lo que asumo es que puede que este usando el metodo incorrecto para agregar este subdocumento al documento creado en mongoDB

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes en el campo de búsqueda, estas realizando una búsqueda sobre un campo que no existe en el Schema. Te detallo la solución:

```
const updateAbono = (req, res = response) => {
  const deudorId = req.params._id;
  const abonado = req.body; 

  Deudor.updateOne( { _id: deudorId } , // Aqui es donde tenias el error, lo buscabas por el campo deudorId que no existe.
     {$push: {abonos: abonado} },
    (error, sucess) => {
      if (error ) {
        console.log(error);
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ message: "Error al actualizar el abono" });
      } 
      else{
          console.log(sucess)
        return res.status(200).json({ message: "Se agrego el abono con exito" });
      }
    });
  };
```

Espero que te haya ayudado, sino pregunta sin dudar.

Un saludo

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, realmemte me has ayudado en este problemita, muchas gracias!!!